# CSS Translate - Unexpected behaviour

Tags: css, css-transforms

I wanted a button to move down a few pixels on hover, but it comes back up again. Shouldn't it stay where it is while you're still hovering on it?

```
<a href="" class="btn">Email Me</a>

.btn {background: #2ecc71; padding: .5em 1em; border-radius: 3px; color:white; font-size: 1.5em; text-shadow:2px 2px 2px #178345; box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #21a559; transition: transform 0.5s ease 0s;}
.btn:hover {background: #28b865; transform: translate(0px, 3px);}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zICBw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `inline` element can't be transformed properly. If you set the `transform` right in normal state, you'll see the transform takes no effect. However it does have a little effect on animation, maybe because while animating, the element's display becomes `inline-block` (or `block` in some other cases, at least while being animated, the `transform` can take effect). After the animation completes, it returns back to `inline`. So the button's position is set back like as the translate transform has no effect.

Your button is actually an `a` element, which has `inline` display by default. You can simply change its display to `inline-block` or `block` and it works OK:

```
.btn {
   /* ... */
   display:inline-block; 
}
```

### [Updated demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iJpGI).

Comment: Damn it, I used block and inline but not inline-block. What a dick. Cheers King.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply transition `top`? You'll need to position the element, but it will accomplish the same without the reversion.

The problem with transitioning on transform is you change the plane the element occupies, which causes the hover state to no longer trigger. One way around this is to also apply a base transform state to the element.

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b94j3/1/)

```
.btn {
    background: #2ecc71;
    padding: .5em 1em;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color:white;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-shadow:2px 2px 2px #178345;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #21a559;
    transition: top .5s ease;
    top:0px;
    position:relative;
}
.btn:hover {
    background: #28b865;
    top:3px;
}
```